# How to get the JSON object index using a key or value in python and delete the entire object matching that index?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

```
Sample JSON:
    [{'ID': '0001',
      'Name': 'Anand',
      'PTime': '8:00'},
     {'ID': '0012',
      'Name': 'Arun',
      'PTime': '8:00'},]
```

How do I get the index of the Object that matches ID == 0012 and delete the entire object using obj.pop(index).

Answer (score 0):

Utilize some [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
sample_json = [{'ID': '0001',
                'Name': 'Anand',
                'PTime': '8:00'},
               {'ID': '0012',
                'Name': 'Arun',
                'PTime': '8:00'},]

[ x for x in sample_json if x['ID'] != '0012' ]
# output
[{'ID': '0001', 'Name': 'Anand', 'PTime': '8:00'}]
```

This will deference the object, and garbage collection will take care of the rest.

You can even just rebind the output to your initial variable name

```
sample_json = [ x for x in sample_json if x['ID'] != '0012' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using filter and lambda:

```
>>> data
[{'ID': '0001', 'PTime': '8:00', 'Name': 'Anand'}, {'ID': '0012', 'PTime': '8:00', 'Name': 'Arun'}]
>>> filter(lambda x:x['ID']=='0012', data)
[{'ID': '0012', 'PTime': '8:00', 'Name': 'Arun'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Or simply use `filter` to find the object and `remove` to delete it from the list.

```
data_list.remove(filter(lambda x:x['ID'] == '0012', data_list)[0])
```